# Movie where aliens implant eggs in astronauts and slowly take over them except for one alien, Sabrina, who lives with her host body

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I watched it on TV in 2002-2004.

As I remember, five or four astronauts receive a SOS signal from a station or ship and go to investigate, only to be attacked by an alien creature very similar to a Xenomorph. They escape but everyone except the main actor is infected with alien eggs (which are located  on the right side of their neck). Slowly the aliens inside them begins taking control of them and ordering them to spread the alien eggs on Earth, except for the main actor's girlfriend who has a "good alien" in her called Sabrina (I think). There was a scene where she is arguing with main actor and he jokingly asks: "Who am I arguing with, you or Sabrina?", "Both" she said.

Later, the astronauts are transformed into aliens by literately ripping their skin and aliens emerge from them, except Sabrina, who sacrifices herself to save the host woman (by leaving the host as a green alien-silhouette).

In the finale, the main actor confronts his old friend who transformed into an alien and kills him with a rocket launcher. The end scene shows some homeless guy wearing the stereo and he is infected with an alien egg on the neck, slowly walking into the night.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Dark Breed* (1996)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116026/plotsummary):

> Captain Saxon, and agent for the top secret Omega agency, has been given the assignment of tracking down and either capturing or killing the crew members of a secret space mission who returned to Earth against orders. It seems that they were all infected with an alien parasite, and they were trying to bring its eggs back to Earth. The eggs were lost in an accident, and both Saxon and the astronauts are trying to locate them. What could the government want them for?

And especially, from [this review](https://www.somethingawful.com/movie-reviews/dark-breed/3/):

> Anyway, **the hot alien reveals that she's actually a good and nice parasite who infested Nick's ex-wife so they could defeat the bad and evil aliens that infested the other astronauts.** They only have 39 hours until the bad aliens hatch and rule the world. I'm not exactly sure how they would go about doing this, but we're just supposed to fixate on the fact that they only have 39 hours left until something awful happens. [...]
>
> **Nick disarms the alien Pod of Doom and blows them all up several times**. It was all so very exciting and... exciting. Random things continue to explode in the background while Nick jumps towards the camera in slow motion. **Nick makes a joke with his now alien-free wife (the alien that possessed her just kind of floats away)** and they walk away into obscurity.

The trailer has aliens totally ripped off from the Xenomorphs (towards the end):

---

Found with the Google query `movie alien eggs neck control earth  site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: That could be it,lemme check on the net