# Movie called "Predator" or "Predator 5" with Predator-like creatures inside of people

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been trying to find this movie for many years now. I remember watching it in around 2005 or so. It wasn't a popular one. In local video centers the movie was rented as "**Predator 5**".

I remember a little bit from the movie, there are group of people including a woman who have some sort of Predator like creatures inside them. There was a scene where a man is on the ground naked and suddenly a tail comes out from his spine. Soon after he got torn apart and a full grown alien comes out and the creature's head is like a battery because as I remember it was similar to a box.

Also there was another scene that all these people with creatures inside were in a highway holding hands when a truck comes in their way.

Another scene, the woman gets shot and she doesn't die, instead the creature inside her dies and comes out of her body like a soul leaving the body.

I am sure it should be a B-grade or low budget movie. Many of my friends remember the movie but no one actually remembers the name.

Comment: Species?? There is a few sequels to that.

Comment: @Seamusthedog: I think you missed the "really bad" there between "few" and "sequels" :p

Comment: I don't see anything under Predator Pastiche (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PredatorPastiche)

Comment: I haven’t actually seen any of them but aware of their existence. Give them a wide berth then?

Comment: No not Species, Also even though the name says Predator it's not related to Predator at all. I don't even think that is the real name, I think just the local people labeled it that way. I've searched Google using everything I know also checked movie suggesting sites. But no luck..

Comment: {nods} You say that there were "predator like" creatures in the people, but your description sounds a bit more like the Xenomorphs from the *Aliens* movies. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Dark Breed* (1996).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116026/plotsummary):

> Captain Saxon, and agent for the top secret Omega agency, has been given the assignment of tracking down and either capturing or killing the crew members of a secret space mission who returned to Earth against orders. It seems that they were all infected with an alien parasite, and they were trying to bring its eggs back to Earth. The eggs were lost in an accident, and both Saxon and the astronauts are trying to locate them. What could the government want them for?

And especially, from [this (hilarious and, by the way) review](https://www.somethingawful.com/movie-reviews/dark-breed/3/):

> For no readily apparent reason, **the alien astronauts decide to leave and stand in front of traffic in the middle of a highway. They get some guy pulling a mobile home to pull over and they hijack his truck and drive off.** Aliens obviously prefer the stylish comfort of a mobile home of something less stupid like a broken down Yugo with peace signs and "GRRL Power!" painted all over it.  [...]
>
> It was all so very exciting and... exciting. Random things continue to explode in the background while Nick jumps towards the camera in slow motion. **Nick makes a joke with his now alien-free wife (the alien that possessed her just kind of floats away)** and they walk away into obscurity.

---

Found by remembering this *Aliens* ripoff I had previously identified for [Movie where aliens implant eggs in astronauts and slowly take over them except for one alien, Sabrina, who lives with her host body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/206295/).

Comment: Possibly worth noting that in some overseas markets, the film was marketed as *parasite* rather than Dark Breed. That could be what OP is thinking of (rather than Predator)

Comment: **Thanks a lot man this is the one**.. Accepting the answer now..